# QGIS Grass Plugin fails with r.cost.vect

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, cost-path

I tried the following in QGIS with the Grass Plugin:

```
r.cost input=preCostSurface@albi start_points=OSMroads@albi output=cost0109 max_cost=0
```

And I get the following error:

```
Dev note: Adapted sites library used for vector points. (module should be updated to GRASS 6 vector library)

￼No start points 
Finished with error
```

What is causing that and how can I fix it?

---

Edit: It seams like this is a general Grass 6.4.3 issue and will be resolved in Grass 7. Does anybody know a workaround for that problem meanwhile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The r.cost GRASS module expects start_points to be a map containing point features. It seems that your map doesn't contain any point features. Try using a map with point features. With QGIS you can easily digitize such a map.

For more information on the parameters see the **[r.cost manual page for GRASS 6.4](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.cost.html)**:

Comment: r.cost.rast takes as input a raster map with starting points. In other words a raster map where all non-NULL cells are considered to be starting points. Is this what your OSMroads map is?

Comment: You are right. I used a line vector layer. I thought that works too. But it doesn't. It only accepts points. I converted the line layer to a raster and used `r.cost.rast`. This way it worked.